# What should I do if I want to add a condition to Android Debounce?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I implemented a feature to automatically search every second for the string entered in the SearchView using Debounce. Clicking the Submit button bypasses the auto-search feature and performs a search. The code in the question works fine, but I want to refactor it. Can you give me some advice??

```
searchView.queryTextChangeEvents()
        .debounce {
            if (it.isSubmitted) {
                Observable.just(it)
            } else {
                Observable.just(it).delay(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            }
        }
        .subscribe { // Search }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information are missing here like what returns `queryTextChangeEvents()` method, so I will  assume that return some `Observable<String>` . In this case, on every text input that observer will be trigger with some keyword.

If I understood, you want to implement an automatic search every 1 second and force search if you press the `search` button. So in this case,  you should be subscribed on two observer:

- Search Button click listener
- Time Trigger every 1 sec

*And `queryTextChangeEvents()` observer is unnecessary.*

Assume that search button has id `searchBtn` and search text input filed has id  `searchView`.
With  [RxBinding library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) you can be subscribed on clicks with `RxView.clicks(searchBtn)`.

And the end, you should merge these two observer `Observable.merge()` and prevent too much searching with debouncing operator.

For example:

```
val timedSearchTrigger = Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
val buttonClickTrigger = RxView.clicks(searchBtn)

Observable.merge(timedSearchTrigger,buttonClickTrigger)
        .debounce(200,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap {api.search(searchView.text)}
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { // search results }
```